# how to combine two mutable arrays values in single mutable array?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


    NSError *error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"json.... %@",json);


    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@", jsonObject);

    NSDictionary *checkArray=[json valueForKey:@"ND"];

    NSArray *tel = [checkArray valueForKey:@"FN"];


    testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    testArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    newsarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for (id photo in tel)
    {
        if (photo == [NSNull null])
        {
            NSString *test8;
            test8 = @"empty";
            [testArray addObject:test8];

        }
        else
        {
            // photo isn't null. It's an array
            NSArray *innerPhotos = photo;

            [testArray addObject:photo];

        }

    }


    NSArray *tel1 = [checkArray valueForKey:@"LN"];

    for (id photo1 in tel1)
    {
        if (photo1 == [NSNull null])
        {
            NSString *test8;
            test8 = @"empty";
            [testArray1 addObject:test8];

        }
        else
        {
            // photo isn't null. It's an array
            //NSArray *innerPhotos1 = photo1;

            [testArray1 addObject:photo1];

        }

    }


    newsarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[testArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:testArray1]];
    NSLog(@"testArray =%@",newsarray);
```

here i want to combine two array values "testArray" and "testArray1"

my mutablearray values are

testArray = aa, bb, cc, dd...
testArray1= xx, yy, zz, ss...

i would like to expect my output like

aa xx, bb yy, cc zz, dd ss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0;i<[testArray count];i++){
    NSString *tmpObject=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                            [testArray objectAtIndex:i],  
                            [testArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];

    [newArray addObject tmpObject];
    tmpObject=nil;
}
```

Comment: what is use of this line :- `[testArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];`

Comment: read complete line  NSString *tmpObject=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[testArray objectAtIndex:i],  
      [testArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];

Comment: ohh ok it my mistak but i dont think that it neead a create newArray they add first in to second array that's it

Comment: thanks for close look..variety of logics available here @nitin ..see all five answers all got different approaches...and thats not exactly duplicate question. 147,721 questions for ios..some similarities will be there for questions coming in future..

Comment: there are lots of similar method for one task right..? so it doesn't mean that  just adding one NSString variable making different   implementation

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below..

```
 NSMutableArray *aryFinal=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int count = [testArray count]+[testArray1 count];
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
 if(i%2==0)
    [aryFinal addobject:[testArray objectAtIndex:i]];
 else
    [aryFinal addobject:[testArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];

 }
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Comment: i'm getting this error "no visible @interface for 'nsmutablearray' declares the selector 'addobject'"

Comment: have you define your array as a NSArray or NSMutableArray???..

Comment: Error cleared. But not working your code...

Comment: what happening? can you tell me my friend ??

Comment: sorry... your code also working

Comment: already i have accepted one answer... that's also working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"AA",@"BB",@"CC" nil];
 NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"XX",@"YY",@"ZZ" nil];

    for (int i=0; i<[array1 count];i++)
        [array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:i 
                withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",
                            array1[i],
                            array2[i]]];
    NSLog(@"%@",array1);
```

**Output:**

> "AA XX","BB YY","CC ZZ"

Answer (score 0):

To simply add two arrays:

```
[testArray setArray: testArray1];
```

But if you want desired result:

```
NSMutableArray *arrFinal=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i = 0; i < (testArray.count + testArray1.count); i++)
{
 if(i%2 == 0)
    [arrFinal addobject:[testArray objectAtIndex:i]];
 else
    [arrFinal addobject:[testArray1 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for aa xx, bb yy, cc zz, dd ss output:

```
int i=-1;
for(int k =0;k<[testArray1 count];++k)
{
    i=i+2;
    [testArray insertObject:[testArray1 objectAtIndex:k] atIndex:i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to go for third array. You can use `replaceObjectAtIndex` method of `NSMutableArray`.

This way..

```
    NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"aa",@"bb", nil];
    NSArray *array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"xx",@"yy", nil];

    for (int i=0; i<[array1 count];i++)
        [array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",array1[i],array2[i]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array1,*array2;
    //////array1 and array2 initialise it with your values
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]

    int totalcount = 0;

    if (array1.count > array2.count) {
       totalcount =  array1.count;
    }
    else
        totalcount =  array2.count;

    for (int i = 0; i<totalcount; i++) {
        if (i <= array1.count-1) {
            [finalArray addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
        if (i <= array2.count-1) {
            [finalArray addObject:[array2 objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
```